# Write text Attribute inside of div tag

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to know how i can add some javascript to add value inside text like below

The original div in HTML code like

```
<div> Text </div>
```

I need the some way to put an value inside the div appear in source like below

```
<div data-texe> Text </div>
```

I have try but its new for me

```
  <script>
        var div = document.getElementByDIV;
        div.innerDIV += 'data-texe';
  </script>
```

Comment: That is not `inside` div, that will be a attribute of `div`.

Comment: What is your goal here? Certainly it's not just to add an attribute to your div that has no value?

Answer (score 1):

You want to set attribute?

```
var div = document.getElementById('yourid');
div.setAttribute('data','texe')
```

Comment: Its fine but need appear code not  data="texe"  only need normal text with dash like ( data-texe-texe) not (data="texe" )

Comment: div.setAttribute('data-texe-texe')

Comment: do you have id test??

Comment: yes ist appear like (id="test">)  not like add ('data-texe-texe')

Comment: In my example it would produce like this: <div id="test" data="texe">

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first find a way to identify your `<div>` elements, either with a unique ID or a class name. In this example I chose a unique ID:

```
<div id="test">Text</div>
```

If you want to add your `data-texe` attribute to *all* `<div>`s, you could use `document.getElementsByTagName()` and then loop over the results.

But let's stick to altering just one element for this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // getElementByDIV is obviously not a valid function, so let's use
    // one that finds an element by its ID:
    var div = document.getElementById('test');

    // The setAttribute function lets you add an attribute to the element
    // The first parameter is the attribute name and the second is its value
    // Attributes with no values are implicitly defined as empty string
    div.setAttribute('data-texe', '');

</script>
```

Comment: Also its fine but need normal text with dash like ( data-texe-texe) not (data-texe="your attribute value")

Comment: @Mohmoh: Custom attributes always have values; both parameters to `setAttribute` are required. Perhaps you can use `undefined` or `null` for the second parameter value.

Comment: Also not repeat it to another div with test id only appear to the first div ?

Comment: @Mohmoh: Please clarify your requirements. All divs, some divs, or one div? If some, which ones. How would you identify only the divs that need the attribute?

Comment: Its fine but it action only on first DIV so how I can make for every DIV that have ID 'test' and replace it with new one ?